# Out-of-sync migrations between development and production environments

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm wondering what's the best way to put the production environment back-in-sync with the development environment. In the "normal situation" when migrations are working, it's not a big deal to drop your development database, and recreate it based on the migrations you have. However it happens quite often that migrations are broken (I mean that the SQL statements are very very messed up) and that fixing them would require much more efforts than simply starting everything from scratch (deleting the database but also the migrations).

This scenario really puzzles me because I'm wondering how to put the development environment back in sync with the production environment.

## Scenario

Database/Code [version of the model]

---

Day 1

## Development

Database 1 | Code  1 | Migrations 1

## Production

Database 1 | Code 1 | Migrations 1

---

Day 2

## Development

Database 4 | Code  4 | Migrations 1 <-> 2 <-> 3 <-> 4

## Production

Database 1 | Code 1 | Migrations 1

Then for whatever reason you made a lot of changes and migrating from 4 to for example 10 generates a really messed up migration class so to avoid spending 1 day on it you start from scratch. Thus :

---

Day 3

## Development

Database 10 | Code 10 | Migrations 1 (started from scratch)

## Production

Database 1 | Code 1 | Migration 1

---

1) How the hell are you going to publish your project to the production environment ? I don't know what's going to happen if you do so, but I guess that an exception page will show up very quickly. So my first question is what is the best way to manage this situation ?

2) To me in a development environment you should be able to recreate your database often to avoid losing time. Do you think that treating the migration classes as first-class citizens and considering that spending 1 day to fix a migration class is not "losing time" is a better approach ?

3) If the answer to 1) to outlines that syncing-back the migrations between production and development environments is not as painful as it seems, I have a sense that for teams who rollover only and don't rollback, getting rid of the old migration classes after a few weeks is fine. Do you see a pitfall here ?

I think being confident in the deployment process is key, for now it's fine I only have a few data on production that I can reinsert manually in case I really need to start from scratch but I don't want to be in a situation where every deployment is either painful (lots of migration scripts to massively correct), or stressful.

Answer (score 1):

I would undo the migrations using 
`Update-Database -TargetMigration` to go back to a state before the migration was applied that I didn't want. [More info here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#specific).

Once it's rolled back, just delete the migration from the Migrations folder. It'll be like it never existed.

So to go back to how it is on Production, just use a `-TargetMigration` to the migration that's currently running on Production, then delete all the ones that come after it, and start again.

Next time you do an `Add-Migration` it'll rescaffold the changes for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem here is that when you have "started from scratch", there is no way to use -TargetMigration since the migration no longer exists on your development machine.

Comment: So don't "start from scratch" unless you truly want to do that - e.g. delete the database, delete all the migrations from the folder. If you really wanted to "start from scratch" then there's a bigger impact on how you're going to deploy it to production. If there's a production database in use, then it's about maintenance, not starting from scratch?

Comment: Sorry if I missed the point, let me know and I'll delete my answer so it shows as unanswered again.

Comment: If I saw that a migration was very screwed up (which does happen), I would just delete that migration before I ran `Update-Database`. I'd then fix the model / the problem, and do another `Add-Migration`. I wouldn't be applying a screwed up migration to my database.

Comment: "there's a production database in use, then it's about maintenance, not starting from scratch?" yea you got it, I think it is part of the issue. Understanding that you are doing maintenance.
I'm interested by what you say "I would just delete that migration before I ran Update-Database. I'd then fix the model / the problem, and do another Add-Migration".
The problem I tried to mention is that very often even when you have a correct model you need to do very involved changes in the migration script, especially when the model gets complex and you made lot of changes.

Comment: But definitely I think that you got it, for the first and 2nd points